# How to get the consecutive items from string

Tags: python

### I need to get the substring which is continuous more than one char

This is my code:

```py
l = []
p = 'abbdccc'
for i in range(len(p)-1):
    m = ''
    if p[i] == p[i+1]:
        m +=p[i]
        l.append(m)
print(l)
```

- My string is 'abbdccc'
- `b` and `c` are repeated more than 1 times
- expected out is `['bb', 'ccc']`

if My string is `'34456788'` then my out is `['44', '88']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution with [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

[v for _, g in groupby(s) if (v := ''.join(g)) and len(v) > 1]
```

Sample run for input string `s`:

```
# input: 'abbdccc'
# output: ['bb', 'ccc']

# input: '34456788'
# output: ['44', '88']
```

Comment: Beautiful use of *warlus* inside the *groupby* to check consecutives .. nice. +1

Comment: why i got syntax error at if (v :=

Comment: It's only available in Python3.8+

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/

Comment: @DanielHao how to write below in 3.8

Answer (score 5):

If using regex is possible or of interest to you, `re.findall` offers a very straightforward way to do this:

```py
inp = "abbdccc"
matches = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r'((.)\2+)', inp)]
print(matches)  # ['bb', 'ccc']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to avoid regex (not sure why as Tim's solution is really elegant):

```
main_str = 'abbdccc'

patterns = []
current_pattern = None
for i, char in enumerate(main_str):
    # First iteration
    if i == 0:
        continue

    if char == main_str[i-1]:
        current_pattern = current_pattern + char if current_pattern else char*2
    elif current_pattern:
        patterns.append(current_pattern)
        current_pattern = None

    # Last iteration
    if current_pattern and i+1 == len(main_str):
        patterns.append(current_pattern)

print(patterns)
```

**Explanation of how it works:**
***First iteration:***
The first iteration is skipped as there is no previous character to compare to.

***Following iterations:***
If the char is equal to previous char:
and if a pattern already exists then just add the char to the current pattern.
But if a current pattern does not exist then do char*2. This works because previous char and char are equal so we are simplifying previous char + char to be char*2.

If the char is not equal to previous char,
then add the current pattern to the previous patterns and clear the current pattern.

***Last iteration:***
This needs to be there, otherwise the current pattern won't get added onto patterns. This is because we only add current_pattern to patterns if the char is different from the previous char but there is no char after the last char to compare to the last char.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in some more itertools - there is one: *more_itertools*, which includes more *powerful* functions.

Here is one that you could try, and put in here as for future reference:

```py
from more_itertools import run_length

s = 'abbdccc' 

print(list(run_length.encode(s))) 
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 1), ('c', 3)]   # return tuples of ('char', count) 

groups = [''.join(x[0]* x[1]) for x in run_length.encode(s) if x[1] > 1]
print(groups)
# ['bb', 'ccc']

# let's see if you're only interested in len(s) >= 3, easy:
groups = [''.join(x[0]* x[1]) for x in run_length.encode(s) if x[1] >= 3]
# ['ccc']
```